# Hero widget inits child widget multiple times

Tags: flutter, dart

Whenever, I have a `Hero` widget about a `StatefulWidget`, the [`State.initState`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html) method is called **three** times instead of once when navigating to that page.
This obviously only happens when the other page also has a `Hero` with the same tag.

```dart
class Page extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(body: Hero(tag: 'tag', child: HeroContent()));
}

class HeroContent extends StatefulWidget {
  HeroContent({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  createState() => _HeroContentState();
}

class _HeroContentState extends State<HeroContent> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    print('_HeroContentState.initState'); // printed three times with `Hero` widget and once without
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Container();
}
```

Whenever I navigate to `Page`, `_HeroContentState.initState` is printed three times (and twice when popping a route).
Fully reproducible example of this [as a gist on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/creativecreatorormaybenot/6758c92ea0b83e931aef3ee3a51c8bba).
If I change the build method of `Page`, to look like this (removing the `Hero` widget):

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(body: HeroContent());
```

Now, `_HeroContentState.initState` is only called **once** as it should be.

How do I avoid `Hero` inserting my widget three times? How can I ensure that `initState` is only called once or have a different method that is only called once?

Comment: I tried running with `Hero` but it just got called once, not 3 times. I used `Page` as `home` in `MaterialApp`

Comment: @CopsOnRoad Well, you need to use the `Hero`.. Have another page that has the same hero and then navigate from that to `Page`.

Comment: OK, I thought you posted the full code.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad Just for you I created a gist: https://gist.github.com/creativecreatorormaybenot/6758c92ea0b83e931aef3ee3a51c8bba

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing you can do about that.

The way `Hero` works is that it moves in different locations in the widget tree in 3 steps:

1. the original location
2. inside Overlay, during the Hero transition
3. in the new page

Usually, for such issue, you'd use a `GlobalKey`, but that is not compatible with `Hero`.

As such, it is probably better to refactor your code such that `initState` doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I solved it by passing a value as a parameter that will only be equal to a different one on the first `initState` call. This way I can differentiate between the first and the other two calls.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot does this approach still work for you? Can you share your code for that? Thanks

Comment: thanks for this only wasted 4 hours  @creativecreatorormaybenot would be interested in seeing how you solved it